# Could someone please share a link to book appointment for Spain visa in San Francisco

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, spain, san-francisco, consulates

I need a visa for for travel to Spain this summer, but can't seem to find a place to book an appointment for the SF consulate.

This is the only thing I've found so far from Google, and it's giving an error: https://www.exteriores.gob.es/es/Paginas/Page-not-found.aspx?requestUrl=https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/SANFRANCISCO/en/Pages/InfoCitas.aspx

Would appreciate the link to the right page! thanks in advance

Comment: How about https://www.educacionyfp.gob.es/eeuu/dam/jcr:6df55a42-b55d-4bc1-8795-2392b886ed2a/2021-nalcap-visado-info-web-sanfrancisco.pdf What's your citizenship? A US citizen doesn't need a Visa for Spain

Comment: Indian. So I definitely do need the schengen visa, unfortunately

Comment: Any luck? They have no one working there processing visas right now.

Comment: @hihello123 Did you end up applying for the visa? How was your experience? Was it easy to get an appointment? How long did the process take?

Answer (score 10):

It would seem that an online booking is not possible.

Based on the text shown below, you must request an appointment per eMail:

- **cog.sanfrancisco@maec.es**

---

From: [Ministerio de Asuntos exteriores, Unión Europea y Cooperación](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/en/Paginas/index.aspx)

- select [Consular services](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/en/ServiciosAlCiudadano/Paginas/Servicios-consulares.aspx)

  - fill in required data:

    - [Consular services, San Francisco, United States, Schengen Visa](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/en/ServiciosAlCiudadano/Paginas/Servicios-consulares.aspx?scco=Estados+Unidos&scd=251&scca=Visados&scs=Visado+de+estancia+(visado+Schengen))

Inside the resulting text you will find:

> **Place of presentation:**
> The application must be submitted in person, at the premises of the Consular Office. It is necessary to request an appointment by writing an email to **cog.sanfrancisco@maec.es**.

(Result as of: 2022-03-12)