# Anyone managed to get a Schengen visa appointment at the Spanish consulate in San Francisco?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, applications, spain, san-francisco

I have emailed them a few times at cog.sanfrancisco.vis@maec.es and have gotten no responses. Our travel dates are coming up fast.

Any advice on how to get an appointment is greatly appreciated!

E.g. will showing up at the embassy help?

---

As reference:

- [Could someone please share a link to book appointment for Spain visa in San Francisco](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/172569/could-someone-please-share-a-link-to-book-appointment-for-spain-visa-in-san-fran/172570#172570)

Comment: Have you tried calling them?

Comment: Yes, but no dice. It's automated message saying all consulate employees are serving customers and email cog.sanfrancisco.vis@maec.es instead

Comment: You could always change plans and travel to a different Schengen country.

Comment: Here the question arises: if a visa appointment is not possible at the appropriate (where the longest period is to be spent) Schengen country, would that be a justified reason to make the application elsewhere?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96308/schengen-visa-appointments-not-available-for-3-months-what-are-my-options When are you planning to travel? The SF consulate looks like your only option to apply. There’s a consulate in LA but you need to reside within their jurisdiction, it might be worth trying them anyway https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/losangeles/en/Paginas/index.aspx Or change your plans and apply for a country served by VFS Global from the US https://www.vfsglobal.com/en/individuals/contact.html

Comment: @hihello123 just curious what was the outcome - when (if ever) did they reply your email?

Answer (score -3):

Schengen visas are usually not obtained via consulates directly but via an intermediate party such as VFS Global.

There seems to be an VFS office in San Francisco. Ask them if they do visas to Spain, book an appointment there.

Comment: Looks like VFS don’t do visas for Spain from the USA, it’s not listed as an option on their website https://www.vfsglobal.com/en/individuals/contact.html

Comment: Spain does not refer those seeking visas to VFS (nor to any other third-party visa processor).  See https://www.exteriores.gob.es/en/ServiciosAlCiudadano/Paginas/Servicios-consulares.aspx?scco=Estados+Unidos&scd=251&scca=Visados&scs=Visado+de+estancia+(visado+Schengen).  VFS does not process visas for Spain in the United States (see their website at https://www.vfsglobal.com/en/individuals/index.html).